# linear map from $\mathbb{R} ^3 $ to $\mathbb{R} ^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear map $ f: \mathbb{R} ^3 \to \mathbb{R} ^2$ such that there exists $ A \subset \mathbb{R} ^3$ which is linearly dependent and $ f(A)$ is linearly independent.

The only thing I thought is that $f$ is not injective. But I can't find such an $f$.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A= \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0)\}$ and define $F$ as following
$$F(1,0,0)= (1,0)$$
$$F(0,1,0)= (1,0)$$
$$F(0,0,1)= (0,1)$$
Extend it lineary; That is 
$$F(x,y,z)= xF(1,0,0)+ yF(0,1,0)+ zF(0,0,1)$$
$$F(x,y,z)= (x+y, z)$$
Then $F(A)=\{(1,0)\}$  which is independent.

Comment: Your set $A$ is not linearly dependent. You could add the vector $(\frac 1 2 , \frac 1 2 , 0)$ to fix this.

Comment: @sebastian,  Yeah you are right.. My mistake.. editing it.. thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete revision of my first (terrible) answer.

$\{\mathbf x\}$ is a perfectly good linearly independent set in $\mathbb R^2$ when $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2) \neq0$.  Consider a $\mathbf y \in \mathbb R^3$ which is orthogonal to $(x_1,x_2,0)$ then $A = \{(x_1,x_2,0)+a\mathbf y\,|\,a\in\mathbb R\}$ is linearly dependent and the [orthogonal projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_projection) onto $\operatorname{span}\{\mathbf x\}$ has the desired property since all elements in $A$ get mapped to $\mathbf x$.

Comment: I think that the null vector in every vector space is linear dependent.

Comment: So if we take $ f \equiv x$ and take $ A=\{ (1,1,1),(1,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ then we are done since $A$ is linear dependent?

Comment: @passenger What do you mean by $f \equiv x$?